# How do I render one Django ModelForm CharField as both a select box and a text box?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django ModelForm for a `CharField` with a set of `choices`. I want to provide the user four inputs: I want three to be multiple selects with the choice options, and the last to be a free text input field. Is there a way to render one `ModelForm` with one Field that has two different input styles?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to modify the widgets used in the model form. It's pretty well documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets). However, here's a quick example that should be what you're looking for.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=FIELD_1_CHOICES))
    field_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=FIELD_2_CHOICES))
    field_3 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=FIELD_3_CHOICES))
    field_4 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', 'field_4']
```

You'll need to define the FIELD_1_CHOICES for each of the fields with whatever options you'd like to give them. Also, you shouldn't have to do the line for field_4 since the `TextInput` is the default widget for a `CharField` but I added it to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom widget to solve the problem, HTML5 allows you to have a free text input with a dropdown list which would work as a pick-one-or-write-other type of field, this is how I made it:

fields.py

```
from django import forms


class ListTextWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, data_list, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListTextWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._name = name
        self._list = data_list
        self.attrs.update({'list':'list__%s' % self._name})

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        text_html = super(ListTextWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
        data_list = '<datalist id="list__%s">' % self._name
        for item in self._list:
            data_list += '<option value="%s">' % item
        data_list += '</datalist>'

        return (text_html + data_list)
```

forms.py

```
from myapp.fields import FormForm

class FormForm(forms.Form):
    char_field_with_list = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _country_list = kwargs.pop('data_list', None)
        super(FormForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # the "name" parameter will allow you to use the same widget more than once in the same
        # form, not setting this parameter differently will cuse all inputs display the
        # same list.
        self.fields['char_field_with_list'].widget = ListTextWidget(data_list=_data_list, name='country-list')
```

views.py

```
from myapp.forms import FormForm

def country_form(request):
    # instead of hardcoding a list you could make a query of a model, as long as
    # it has a __str__() method you should be able to display it.
    country_list = ('Mexico', 'USA', 'China', 'France')
    form = FormForm(data_list=country_list)

    return render(request, 'my_app/country-form.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```